# »Nach« in sentences

Tags: preposition

It has these two sentences:

> Er hat mich in fließendem Chinesisch nach dem Weg gefragt.
>   Sie fragt die Frau nach dem Weg.

What's the purpose of »nach« in the sentences?
Is it just there to indicate what was being asked about?

Comment: Check the dictionary: nach etwas fragen means to ask about or for something.

Comment: The combination of Swiss quotation marks and *ß* looks weird to me.

Answer (score 2):

How a specific verb is connected to its arguments is a question of grammar and not easily understood especially to people speaking other languages. In English, the verb *to ask* uses the extension *for something.* Thus, in English the sentences would be:

> He asked for the way in fluent Chinese.
>
> She asked the lady for the way.

Similarly, you can ask *for a tissue, for money* etc.

In French, the thing you are asking for is connected to the verb as a direct object.

> Il a demandé la voie en chinois.

In German, it is connected as a prepositional object using the preposition *nach:*

> Er hat sie in fließendem Chinesisch nach dem Weg gefragt.
>
> Sie hat die Frau nach dem Weg gefragt.

It is thus always helpful to learn the arguments of a verb together with a verb. Thus, you should be learning that German *nach etwas fragen* corresponds to English *to ask for something.*

Answer (score 0):

It's just a preposition used in an abstract context. In English you'd also use a preposition: Ask *about* the way or ask *for* the way